# App crashes while using custom fonts in iOS 9 beta 5

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, ios-9-beta3

My app is in app store which supports iOS 7.1.2 to iOS 8.4 and it is working fine till 8.4 version. When I tried to run the same app on iOS 9 beta 5 its getting crashed.It was working fine in iOS 9 beta 4. After debugging I found that the crash is due to the custom font we have used in our app. Is this the problem with iOs 9 beta 5 ? What should I do to support my app on iOS 9.0 main release which will be expecting in a week.

Below is the stack trace of crash

> - thread #1: tid = 0x6d68, 0x0000000184d6e1a4 CoreText`OTL::GPOS::ApplyPairPos(OTL::LookupSubtable const*,
>     OTL::TGlyphIterator&, OTL::Coverage const&) const + 636, queue =
>     'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>     address=0x3020451cc)
>     frame #0: 0x0000000184d6e1a4 CoreText`OTL::GPOS::ApplyPairPos(OTL::LookupSubtable const*,
>     OTL::TGlyphIterator&, OTL::Coverage const&) const + 636
>     frame #1: 0x0000000184d72b14 CoreText`OTL::GPOS::ApplyLookupSubtable(OTL::Lookup const&, unsigned
>     int, OTL::LookupSubtable const*, OTL::TGlyphIterator&, OTL::Coverage
>     const&) const + 116
>     frame #2: 0x0000000184d81690 CoreText`OTL::GPOS::ApplyLookups(TRunGlue&, int, OTL::GlyphLookups&)
>     const + 544
>     frame #3: 0x0000000184d80dc0 CoreText`TOpenTypePositioningEngine::PositionRuns(SyncState&,
>     KerningStatus&) + 628
>     frame #4: 0x0000000184cea7b4 CoreText`TKerningEngine::PositionGlyphs(TRunGlue&, ShapingType,
>     AnnexTableFlag) + 188
>     frame #5: 0x0000000184ce90a4 CoreText`CTFontTransformGlyphs + 440
>     frame #6: 0x000000019504c85c UIFoundation`__NSStringDrawingEngine + 8788
>     frame #7: 0x000000019504a5bc UIFoundation`-[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing)
>     boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 156
>     frame #8: 0x0000000189731724 UIKit`-[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 780
>     frame #9: 0x000000018973137c UIKit`-[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 132
>     frame #10: 0x000000018982c548 UIKit`-[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 72
>     frame #11: 0x000000018982c3a8 UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>     _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 48
>     frame #12: 0x000000018982bdbc UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints]
> - 588
>     frame #13: 0x0000000189827e5c UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 244
>     frame #14: 0x000000018982bb60 UIKit`-[UILabel updateConstraints] + 220
>     frame #15: 0x0000000189f28c8c UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 460
>     frame #16: 0x0000000189f28ef4 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 200
>     frame #17: 0x0000000189f28bbc UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 252
>     frame #18: 0x00000001850b0c00 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
>     frame #19: 0x000000018982ab78 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
>     frame #20: 0x0000000189f28ec8 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 156
>     frame #21: 0x0000000189f28bbc UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 252
>     frame #22: 0x0000000189f28ef4 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:]
> - 200
>     frame #23: 0x000000018982ba5c UIKit`__60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 100
>     frame #24: 0x00000001850b0c00 Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
>     frame #25: 0x000000018982ab78 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 64
>     frame #26: 0x000000018982b690 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] +
>     244
>     frame #27: 0x0000000189848094 UIKit`-[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] +
>     108
>     frame #28: 0x0000000189f29598 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>     _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 268
>     frame #29: 0x0000000189a27808 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 176
>     frame #30: 0x0000000189722640 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 688
>     frame #31: 0x0000000188f31f14 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
>     frame #32: 0x0000000188f2cb20 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
>     frame #33: 0x0000000188f2c9e0 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) +
>     32
>     frame #34: 0x0000000188f2c07c QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
>     frame #35: 0x0000000188f2bdd0 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 516
>     frame #36: 0x0000000188f254bc QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(**CFRunLoopObserver*,
>     unsigned long, void*) + 80
>     frame #37: 0x00000001841cc768 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
> - 32
>     frame #38: 0x00000001841ca50c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
>     frame #39: 0x00000001840f98c0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
>     frame #40: 0x00000001897931ec UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 460
>     frame #41: 0x000000018978e0d4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204   * frame #42: 0x000000010004eb08 SampleFont`main(argc=1,
>     argv=0x000000016fdb7af0) + 124 at main.m:14
>     frame #43: 0x00000001994ae8b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Comment: We are experiencing custom fonts issue in 8.0 and 8.0.2 as well.App is crashing at CTFontTransformGlyphs.

Comment: App is still crashing in iOS 9 and it is working fine in iOS 9.1 beta. Seems apple has made changes in Font family and they are aware of this issue. Thats why they have released the iOS 9 and iOS 9.1 beta on same day.

Comment: now i am facing crash while using the telugu script in my app only in iOS 9